Subset all the years between 1984 and 2024 in HLS collection but only between July and September
I want to extract the data from EarthData. I found a way to get all the years between 1984 and 2024 (this is more than the coverage of the data, but I just want a subset of all the years) that are between the month of 1st of july and 15th of september.
library(rstac)
items <- stac("https://cmr.earthdata.nasa.gov/stac/LPCLOUD/") |> 
  stac_search(collections = list("HLSS30_2.0", "HLSL30_2.0"),
              bbox = c(-73.72, 45.55, -73.53, 45.57),
              limit = 100,
              datetime = '1984-07-01T00:00:00Z/2024-09-15T23:59:59Z'
              ) |> 
  rstac::ext_filter(
      datetime > "2016-07-01"
  ) |>
  post_request()

print(items)

However, when I use ext_filter() it doesn't filter the data and I can't find a way to get all the years but only for the months I want. It seems there is a way to specify the julian date as this is what is in the HLS naming convention (https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/data/get-started-data/collection-overview/missions/harmonized-landsat-sentinel-2-hls-overview/#hls-naming-conventions).

Is there a way to subset the data directly from the stac_search with all the years but only certain months?
Is it possible to subset the data in another way if the first option is not possible?
Is there a way to have a for loop that searches for all years (see an example to combine the years) in the database, but combine the items together ?

y <- 2020
t1 = paste0(paste0(y, "-07-01"), 'T00:00:00Z')
t2 = paste0(paste0(y, "-09-15"), 'T23:59:59Z')
roi_datetime <- paste(t1, t2, sep = '/')


YYYYDDD in the naming convention points toward as.POSIXlt(strptime('2024-09-1', format = '%Y-%m-%d', tz = 'UTC'))$yday [1] 244. as.POSIXlt(strptime('1984-07-01', format = '%Y-%m-%d', tz = 'UTC'))$yday [1] 182. So, YYYY182:YYYY244. You could regex and test if last three digits before 'T' fall into your desired range of days, HLS.S30.T60HTE.2022103T222539.v2.0.B01.tif. Sorry, doesn't address operations of rstac at all, but imagining if rstac didn't exist , but filter by time/space is covered rstac tutorial

Thanks! From what I've seen the ext_filter is actually collection dependent (and I wasn't able to make it work with HLS). https://github.com/brazil-data-cube/rstac/issues/145. The other issue is that when I use the full dataset, I'm limited by the number of files it can query. So it would be better to have that filter upfront.

Over at brazil-data-cube, searching 'datetime' is an avenue I'm looking at. The docs say the server 'can' do temporal, so are the provided rstac regex doing what they think (I should look for tests)... I think you get more visibility by reopening there rather and commenting on closed issue, which was rather a work around, but kadyb is a careful coder in terra space.

You got a response bring it all down and filter locally, not ideal perhaps, but seemingly server side capabilities issue, which, helpfully, how to query those capabilities is shown.

Yes! Thanks, I responded. Since it's seems more of a server limitation, I thought that it could be nice to have a way to loop through the year (hence the last part of the question) and combine the items object. So that in the end, you only have one items object, as if it was queried once.

I think you can still get there based off a kind of list.files() all files approach, locally index the keepers based on above, ask for those. I'll install rstac to test when current project allows.
